# Get the ID of the column being read in SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, reader

I'm currently reading from an ancient stored procedure.

I know you can get the `FieldType` and `FieldCount` to get type/size of the columns but is there a way to get the actual `ID` of the column to read from the `reader`?

The `ID` I'm referring to is this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject{
        SomeProperty = reader["ID"]
    };
}
```

I don't want to bind it arbitrarily to some `var` but to obtain the actual `column name` it's returning in the results set if possible?

Comment: in short: `reader.GetName(ordinal)` and `reader.GetOrdinal(name)` are the index<==>name mapping functions here; combine with `reader.FieldCount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that and gather all name that contains in reader:

```
var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
```